# How can I parse coronavirus data from this site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am beginner at Python and i don't know so much about getting data from the internet. This method that i used here worked at fetching and printing IMDB Top 250 Movies. So i want to do the same thing to [this coronavirus data](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/). But unlike to the IMDB data, program didn't treat items as a list. I couldn't see so much difference from the IMDB data. So how can i print at least countries' names by using simple requests and beautiful soup like this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
new_soup = soup.find_all("table", {"id":"main_table_countries_today"})
country_table = new_soup[0].contents[3]
country_table = country_table.find_all("tr")
for country in country_table:
    country_name = country.find_all("td", {"style":"font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; text-align:left;"})
    print(country_name[0].text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been taking the data from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19) of [John Hopkins University](https://www.jhu.edu/), which is considered a reputable source:

```
names = ('confirmed', 'deaths', 'recovered')
src_base = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_{name}_global.csv'
```

which can be fecthed with [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/):

```
import requests


for name, url in src.items():
    response = requests.get(url)
```

and conveniently converted to a Pandas dataframe:

```
import io
import pandas


dfs = {}
for name, url in src.items():
    response = requests.get(url)
    dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    print(name, url)
    print(dfs[name])
```

```
confirmed https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv
                Province/State         Country/Region  ...  4/13/20  4/14/20
0                          NaN            Afghanistan  ...      665      714
1                          NaN                Albania  ...      467      475
2                          NaN                Algeria  ...     1983     2070
3                          NaN                Andorra  ...      646      659
4                          NaN                 Angola  ...       19       19
..                         ...                    ...  ...      ...      ...
259  Saint Pierre and Miquelon                 France  ...        1        1
260                        NaN            South Sudan  ...        4        4
261                        NaN         Western Sahara  ...        6        6
262                        NaN  Sao Tome and Principe  ...        4        4
263                        NaN                  Yemen  ...        1        1

[264 rows x 88 columns]
deaths https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv
                Province/State         Country/Region  ...  4/13/20  4/14/20
0                          NaN            Afghanistan  ...       21       23
1                          NaN                Albania  ...       23       24
2                          NaN                Algeria  ...      313      326
3                          NaN                Andorra  ...       29       31
4                          NaN                 Angola  ...        2        2
..                         ...                    ...  ...      ...      ...
259  Saint Pierre and Miquelon                 France  ...        0        0
260                        NaN            South Sudan  ...        0        0
261                        NaN         Western Sahara  ...        0        0
262                        NaN  Sao Tome and Principe  ...        0        0
263                        NaN                  Yemen  ...        0        0

[264 rows x 88 columns]
recovered https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_recovered_global.csv
                Province/State         Country/Region  ...  4/13/20  4/14/20
0                          NaN            Afghanistan  ...       32       40
1                          NaN                Albania  ...      232      248
2                          NaN                Algeria  ...      601      691
3                          NaN                Andorra  ...      128      128
4                          NaN                 Angola  ...        4        5
..                         ...                    ...  ...      ...      ...
245  Saint Pierre and Miquelon                 France  ...        0        0
246                        NaN            South Sudan  ...        0        0
247                        NaN         Western Sahara  ...        0        0
248                        NaN  Sao Tome and Principe  ...        0        0
249                        NaN                  Yemen  ...        0        0

[250 rows x 88 columns]
```

and you could eventually have some quick plots:

[image: confirmed]
[image: deaths]
[image: recovered]

Full code available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/123OBCm4WGoPYMQG_kK3lLwkaPbrJrGrT).